# HTML -> same link doesn't work on different html pages of my website

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, href

I put a link to a wikipedia page through this line of HTML :

```
<div class="voiraussi">
          <h2>Voir aussi</h2><br>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Turing" target="_blank">Biographie d'Alan Turing</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARPANET" target="_blank">ARPANET, ancêtre technique d'Internet</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Those two links work on one of my pages (i have 5 .html files) but on the others, it doesn't work at all, i have no idea why. Those lines above are part of the footer of my website, i copy/paste the footer on all the pages, so i don't understand. I checked on the existing posts but didn't find anything that could help...
Thanks in advance !

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Do the links not take you anywhere? Have you checked the console for errors and disabled any addons in your browser?

Comment: On one of my page, the links work, i can click on the text and it goes to the wikipedia page i want. On all the other pages, i just cannot click on it, it's like a simple text with no hyperlink. It's really stranged because like i said, the footer is copy/paste, it's the same on every html pages with same CSS properties.

Comment: @j08691 try setting `display: block` to the anchor tag. Or check if there's another element with a higher `z-index` overlapping the footer links.

Comment: Tried your options, didn't work. Something is overlapping because when i go on my 1080p screen, the links are clickable. I tried putting background-color: blue; on every single thing on my css to check if something is overlapping, haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand after looking at your comments and the question, you have some sort element overlayed on the links on the pages where the links are unresponsive. One quick hack to check if this is actually the issue would be to give one or both the links a greater z-index. Try this:

```
<div class="voiraussi">
  <h2>Voir aussi</h2><br>
  <ul>
    <li><a style="z-index:100" href="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Turing" target="_blank">Biographie d'Alan Turing</a></li>
    <li><a style="z-index:100" href="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARPANET" target="_blank">ARPANET, ancêtre technique d'Internet</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i tried what you said, it didn't work. Do you have any more idea ?

Comment: I'd suggest increasing the z-index of the footer itself. Try increasing it by a power of 10 each time, until the links become responsive (i.e try 10, then 100, then 1000 and so on)